# Row to column and column to row using awk

Tags: awk

I have two files containing as below

```
cat file1.txt
a b c 
1 2 3

cat file2.txt
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

I want file1 to be arranged as

```
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

and file2 to be arranged as

```
a b c
1 2 3
```

I would like a solution using awk one line

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some `awk` version

```
awk 1 RS=" |\n" file1  # gnu awk version
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' file1 # portable version
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

```
awk '{printf "%s" (NR%3==0?RS:FS),$1}' file2
a b c
1 2 3
```

`printf "%s"`  # print pararameter #1 ($1)
`NR%3==0?"RS:FS` # add extra formatting. Test if line is number 3.  If its not, use FS (a blank space), if it is use RS, a new line.
So this adjust the next parameter after every 3 line.

Comment: As a newbie of awk, i was not able to understand the solution for file2 fully. Would be grateful if you could explain it

Comment: @jotne Don't forget the comma separating the format from the data. It's cleaner to use `FS` and `RS` and switch the order saves the explicit comparison `awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%3?FS:RS)}'`.

Comment: @sudo_O Yes its cleaner, did not thought about it.  &user2949699 I added some extra info for you, hoping it helps some.

Comment: There seem to be a missing `"` in there, since I get the **`unterminated string`** error with the 2nd example.

Comment: @not2qubit fixed.  Removed "

Answer (score 19):

I'd use `xargs` for this:

```
$ xargs -n1 < file1
a
b
c
1
2
3

$ xargs -n3 < file2
a b c
1 2 3
```

Comment: I liked this solution for its simplicity. But was looking for an awk solution.

Comment: Nice one..I didn't see before

Comment: Really like this one and I search for a while to get this solution, thanks (+1)

Comment: How do I make use of this If I wanted `'a', 'b', 'c', '1', '2', '3'`?

Comment: How to use `xargs -n1` on the output of some other command? I mean, instead of writing the output to a file and use `< file` I'd like to write a single command line (like when we do for `cat file | wc -l` for example).

Answer (score 6):

The idiomatic awk approach of simply setting the OFS or ORS to the FS or RS as appropriate before printing (and recompiling the record if necessary with `$1=$1`) will work with any awk:

```
$ cat file1
a b c
1 2 3
$ awk '{OFS=RS;$1=$1}1' file1
a
b
c
1
2
3
$ cat file2
a
b
c
1
2
3
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%3?FS:RS)}1' file2
a b c
1 2 3
```

Comment: I don't understand the part about recompiling the record. It seems to be necessary, why the "if" - does that depend on the awk implementation? Why is it necessary to recompile it at all? Is there a better way to describe the action than "recompile"?

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин what I said applies to all awk implementations. As you can see we don't recompile the record in the 2nd script, we just change ORS, so it's not always necessary. It's necessary if you want to print the current record with every FS replaced with the OFS. I don't know of a better word for it than recompile but maybe you could say reconstruct or recombine or similar instead if you prefer?

Answer (score 2):

*This answer elaborates on Ed Morton's terse answer. He has rejected my edits to his answers in the past so I'm posting this as a separate answer.*

---

Setting the OFS or ORS to the value of FS or RS should work with any awk. These variables have a [special meaning](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_03) in awk.

Note that the quirky  `{ instruction }1` construct is equivalent to `{ instruction } { print }` because the fundamental structure of the awk language is

```
expression { instructions }
more_expressions { more instructions }
```

So the {}1 construct means roughly this:

```
«implicit true» { code }«1 -> true» «{default instruction -> print}»
```

Input:

```
$ cat file1
a b c
1 2 3

$ cat file2
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

For the first case, we have to reassign the record in order to make awk recompute the number of fields to output.

```
$ awk '{OFS=RS;$1=$1}1' file1
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

The [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Output-Separators.html) contains some hints about why reassigning the field might be necessary (*The usual place to reassign OFS, ORS, etc is in the BEGIN rule before any input is processed*). And curiously, this gives the same result, without reassigning the fields. I guess there is more than one way to make awk re-evaluate the fields:

```
$ awk '{OFS=RS} { print $1, $2, $3 }' file1
a
b
c
1
2
3
```

Second case:

```
$ awk '{ ORS = (NR % 3 ? FS : RS) }1' file2
a b c
1 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For yout first file, you could try something like :

```
awk '{for (i=1 ; i <= NF ; i++) print $i}' file1.txt
```

For your second file, you could try something like :

```
awk 'BEGIN {str=""; i=1} {if(i%3 == 0){str=str""$0"\n"} else {str=str""$0" "} i++} END {print str}' file2.txt
```

However, I'd to make some assumptions like that the whole 3 lines need to skip a line in the output, for example. We would need more details I think ...

Comment: You do not need `-F " "` since its default.