# AWK: convert string to a column

Tags: awk

I want to convert string (eg: `abcdef`) to a column

This is what I want.

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I know how to covert string to column by using `sed`

```
$ echo abcdef | sed 's/[^.]/&\n/g'|sed '$d'
```

But how to covert it using `awk`?

Comment: Maybe yo can see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752644/row-to-column-and-column-to-row-using-awk)

Comment: not awk, but much handier: `echo abcdef | grep -o .`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the field separator to an empty string, so that every character is a different field. Then, loop through them and print:

```
$ awk -v FS="" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' <<< "abcdef"
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Which [is equivalent to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31135446/1983854):

```
awk -F "" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i}' <<< "abcdef"
```

Comment: You can also use split, but you need to make sure to control awk's sorting (by default it is unsorted): `awk 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"} {split ($0,arr,"");for (i in arr){print arr[i]}}' <<< "abcdefg"`

Answer (score 3):

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ awk -v ORS= 'gsub(/./,"&\n")' <<<"abcdefgh"
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
```

Comment: This prints an extra line at the end.

Comment: Just add `-v ORS=` to avoid adding a trailing newline: `awk -v ORS= 'gsub(/./,"&\n")'`. FYI the posted solutions that rely on setting`FS=""` are gawk-specific while this will work in any awk.

Answer (score 0):

Only working with awks internal variables:

```
echo abcdef | awk 'BEGIN{FS="";OFS="\n"}{$1=$1}1'
```

It sets the input field separator (`FS`) to nothing which means that every character is a field. The output field separator (`OFS`) is set to newline. Notive the `$1=$1` is needed to rebuild the record with the new `OFS`.