# How to set the field separator to an empty string?

Tags: awk, gawk

The awk manual indicates that both `-v FS` and `-F` are equivalent ways to set the field separator.

[The GNU Awk User’s Guide -> 4.5.4 Setting FS from the Command Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Command-Line-Field-Separator):

> FS can be set on the command line. You use the `-F' argument to do so.
>
> (...)
>
> The value used for the argument to `-F' is processed in exactly the
>   same way as assignments to the built-in variable FS.

However, I noticed that there is a difference if we set it to an empty string, it is not the same. Tested on my `GNU Awk 4.1.1`.

This works:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $2}' <<< "a,b,c"
b
$ awk -v FS=, '{print $2}' <<< "a,b,c"
b
```

But this does not:

```
$ awk -F="" '{print $2}' <<< "abc"
                                      # $1 contains abc
$ awk -v FS="" '{print $2}' <<< "abc"
b
```

Why? Is this because setting `FS` to empty is a `gawk` specific?

Comment: You have set it to `=`

Comment: @User112638726 oh, true! `awk -F="" '{print $2}' <<< "ab=c"` returns `c`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like you can do this:

```
$ awk -F '' '{print $2}' <<< "abc"
b
```

Tested on GNU awk (versions 3.0.4 and 4.1.1) and mawk version 1.2

To be clear, the **space** between `-F` and `''` is **important**!

Comment: Cool, this makes it! Then I noticed `awk -F=","` doesn't work either, so it is probably because `-F` needs the parameter to be given either "glued" or after a space (POSIX way?)

Comment: @fedorqui Short options (generally) don't use `=` so `-F=","` is the same as `-F=,` which is the same as `FS="=,"`. The space between `-F` and `''` is important because `-F''` just becomes `-F` and then it still needs an argument.

Comment: @EtanReisner nice! Is this a POSIX standard or applies to any kind of cases?

Comment: The POSIX spec for utilities is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html). Guideline 3 says options are single characters. Guideline 6 says options and arguments should be separated by a space. It doesn't cover long options at all that I can see. The behavior above is general getopt operation as far I'm aware but I can't confidently state more than that. If rici or mklement0 see this they'll probably be able to give more concrete answers.

Comment: The reason why this happens is the way Bash processes the command line, not Awk. Bash eats an empty string when it is pressed against a variable, I spoke to the Bash maintainers about this a few months ago. This affects all command line utilities including `read`. E.g. `while read -d '' a b` is not the same as `while read -d'' a b`.

Answer (score 5):

> Why? Is this because setting FS to empty is a gawk specific?

Note that the standards say that the results are unspecified if an empty string is assigned to `FS`. Some versions of `awk` will produce the output you showed above in your example. The version of `awk` on `OS/X` issues the warning and output.

```
awk: field separator FS is empty
```

So the special meaning of setting `FS` to an empty string, does not work in every `awk`.

Comment: Nice! In fact I think it is `gawk` specific.

Comment: @fedorqui correct. idk what mawk would do with it, but nawk will report a warning (like the above) and use the default FS while /usr/xpg4/bin/awk will treat it like the whole record is a single field.