# Why different results with longhand and shorthand versions of FS?

Tags: macos, bash, awk, gnu

Using `awk` to parse a string on the command line character by character:

```
echo "foo" | awk 'BEGIN { FS = "" }{ for (n=1; n<=NF; n++ ) print $n }'
```

works fine. We can also set the value of FS on the command line. However this:

```
echo "foo" | awk -F '' '{ for (n=1; n<=NF; n++ ) print $n }'
```

yields the following error message:

```
awk: field separator FS is empty
```

Why don't both methods return identical results?

Important: GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

Comment: Did you mean to miss off the trailing `'` in the second example?

Comment: with the edit, second statement works

Comment: Oops. Just corrected that.

Comment: @amdixon Are you sure you tested this on a os x shell?

Comment: nope - missed that. not on an osx

Comment: I'll emphasize that in the question, then.

Comment: mine was on ubuntu, GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) and GNU Awk 4.0.1

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135251/how-to-set-the-field-separator-to-an-empty-string)? (the second, unaccepted answer).

Comment: Thanks @Droppy, I hadn't found that explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Update your version of **awk**?

```
$ bash --version | head -n1
GNU bash, version 4.3.42(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
$ gawk --version | head -n 1
GNU Awk 4.1.1, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.3, GNU MP 6.0.0)
$ mawk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan

compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040
$ echo "foo" | gawk -F '' '{ for (n=1; n<=NF; n++ ) print $n }'
f
o
o
$ echo "foo" | mawk -F '' '{ for (n=1; n<=NF; n++ ) print $n }'
f
o
o
$ echo "foo" | gawk 'BEGIN { FS = "" }{ for (n=1; n<=NF; n++ ) print $n }'
f
o
o
$ echo "foo" | mawk 'BEGIN { FS = "" }{ for (n=1; n<=NF; n++ ) print $n }'
f
o
o
```