# How can I replace all middle characters with '*'?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would like to replace middle of word with ****.

For example :

```
ifbewofiwfib
wofhwifwbif
iwjfhwi
owfhewifewifewiwei
fejnwfu
fehiw
wfebnueiwbfiefi
```

Should become :

```
if********ib
wo*******if
iw***wi
ow**************ei
fe***fu
fe*iw
wf***********fi
```

So far I managed to replace all but the first 2 chars with:

```
sed -e 's/./*/g3'
```

Or do it the long way:

```
grep -o '^..' file > start
cat file | sed 's:^..\(.*\)..$:\1:' | awk -F. '{for (i=1;i<=length($1);i++) a=a"*";$1=a;a=""}1' > stars
grep -o '..$' file > end
paste -d "" start stars > temp
paste -d "" temp end > final
```

Comment: And what have you done so far ? Where are you blocked at ? What are you looking for exactly ?

Comment: so far I managed to replace all but the first 2 chars with sed -e 's/./*/g3'
or grep first 2 chars and then grep last 2 chars use sed to change the rest to ** and use paste to stick them back together.

The goal is to replace all chars between first 2 and last 2 chars with * in all lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use Awk for this, if you have a GNU Awk to set the field separator to an empty string ([How to set the field separator to an empty string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31135251/1983854)).

This way, you can loop through the chars and replace the desired ones with "*". In this case, replace from the 3rd to the 3rd last:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{for (i=3; i<=NF-2; i++) $i="*"} 1' file
if********ib
wo*******if
iw***wi
ow**************ei
fe***fu
fe*iw
wf***********fi
```

Answer (score 3):

If `perl` is okay:

```
$ perl -pe 's/..\K.*(?=..)/"*" x length($&)/e' ip.txt
if********ib
wo*******if
iw***wi
ow**************ei
fe***fu
fe*iw
wf***********fi
```

- `..\K.*(?=..)` to match characters other than first/last two characters

  - See [regex lookarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) section for details
- `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in replacement section
- `"*" x length($&)` use length function and string repetition operator to get desired replacement string

Comment: That's a nice way to do, well done! This is something Perl has and I miss in Awk.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with a repetitive substitution, e.g.:

```
sed -E ':a; s/^(..)([*]*)[^*](.*..)$/\1\2*\3/; ta'
```

#### Explanation

This works by repeating the substitution until no change happens, that is what the `:a; ...; ta` bit does. The substitution consists of 3 matched groups and a non-asterisk character:

- `(..)` the start of the string.
- `([*]*)` any already replaced characters.
- `[^*]` the character to be replaced next.
- `(.*..)` any remaining characters to replace and the end of the string.

#### Alternative GNU sed answer

You could also do this by using the hold space which might be simpler to read, e.g.:

```bash
h                                 # save a copy to hold space
s/./*/g3                          # replace all but 2 by *
G                                 # append hold space to pattern space
s/^(..)([*]*)..\n.*(..)$/\1\2\3/  # reformat pattern space
```

Run it like this:

```
sed -Ef parse.sed input.txt
```

#### Output in both cases

```
if********ib
wo*******if
iw***wi
ow**************ei
fe***fu
fe*iw
wf***********fi
```

Comment: nice.. could also use `(.*..)$` instead of `([^*]*)(..)$`

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you on same. It should work in any kind of `awk` versions.

```
awk '{len=length($0);for(i=3;i<=(len-2);i++){val=val "*"};print substr($0,1,2) val substr($0,len-1);val=""}'  Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  len=length($0);
  for(i=3;i<=(len-2);i++){
    val=val "*"};
  print substr($0,1,2) val substr($0,len-1);
  val=""
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:***  Adding explanation now for above code too.

```
awk '
{
  len=length($0);                           ##Creating variable named len whose value is length of current line.
  for(i=3;i<=(len-2);i++){                  ##Starting for loop which starts from i=3 too till len-2 value and doing following:
    val=val "*"};                           ##Creating a variable val whose value is concatenating the value of it within itself.
  print substr($0,1,2) val substr($0,len-1);##Printing substring first 2 chars and variable val and then last 2 chars of the current line.
  val=""                                    ##Nullifying the variable val here, so that old values should be nullified for this variable.
}
' Input_file                                ##Mentioning the Input_file name here.
```