# Splitting a large, complex one column file into several columns with awk

Tags: bash, awk, field, rows

I have a text file produced by some commercial software, looking like below. It consists in brackets delimited sections, each of which counts several million elements but the exact value changes from one case to another.

```
(1
 2
 3
...
)
(11
22
33
...
)
(111
222
333
...
)
```

I need to achieve an output like:

```
 1;  11;   111
 2;  22;   222
 3;  33;   333
...  ...  ...
```

I found a complicated way that is:

- perform sed operations to get

  ```
  1
  2
  3
  ...
  #
  11
  22
  33
  ...
  #
  111
  222
  333
  ...
  ```
- use awk as follows to split my file in several sub-files

  ```
  awk -v RS="#" '{print > ("splitted-" NR ".txt")}'
  ```
- remove white spaces from my subfiles again with sed

  ```
  sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' splitted*.txt
  ```
- join everything together:

  ```
  paste splitted*.txt > out.txt
  ```
- add a field separator (defined in my bash script)

  ```
  awk -v sep=$my_sep 'BEGIN{OFS=sep}{$1=$1; print }' out.txt > formatted.txt
  ```

I feel this is crappy as I loop over million lines several time. 
Even if the return time is quite OK (~80sec), I'd like to find a full awk solution but can't get to it.
Something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="(\\n)"; OFS=";"} { print something } '
```

I found some related questions, especially this one [row to column conversion with awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19752644/row-to-column-and-column-to-row-using-awk), but it assumes a constant number of lines between brackets which I can't do.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS and true multi dimensional arrays:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    RS  = "(\\s*[()]\\s*)+"
    OFS = ";"
}
NR>1 {
    cell[NR][1]
    split($0,cell[NR])
}
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=NF; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=2; colNr<=NR; colNr++) {
            printf "%6s%s", cell[colNr][rowNr], (colNr<NR ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
     1;    11;   111
     2;    22;   222
     3;    33;   333
   ...;   ...;   ...
```

Comment: very nice way to use the ternary operator to solve the OFS ORS problem.

Comment: Incredibly clear and efficient ! 

Got a 39seconds return time.

Comment: Thanks. For your next question - accepting the first answer you get isn't a great idea since it discourages people from posting other answers. If you get extremely lucky and that first answer is the best possible answer then you're good to go, but if you're not that lucky.... Right now there's probably other people who could provide good answers (maybe better then mine or any other one posted so far) looking at your question, seeing you already accepted an answer, and moving on. Just sayin'....

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for sharing this sir, could you please explain this `(\\s*[()]\\s*)+` regex in RS will be grateful to you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it's so every combination of individual or pairs of `)` and `(` are treated as a RS so it captures `(` alone at the start of the file and `)\n` alone at the end of the file as well as every `\n)\n(` pair in the middle of it.

Answer (score 4):

If you know you have 3 columns, you can do it in a very ugly way as following:

```
pr -3ts <file>
```

All that needs to be done then is to remove your brackets:

```
$ pr -3ts ~/tmp/f | awk 'BEGIN{OFS="; "}{gsub(/[()]/,"")}(NF){$1=$1; print}'
1; 11; 111
2; 22; 222
3; 33; 333
...; ...; ...
```

You can also do it in a single awk line, but it just complicates things. The above is quick and easy.

This awk program does the full generic version:

```
awk 'BEGIN{r=c=0}
     /)/{r=0; c++; next}
     {gsub(/[( ]/,"")}
     (NF){a[r++,c]=$1; rm=rm>r?rm:r}
     END{ for(i=0;i<rm;++i) {
            printf a[i,0];
            for(j=1;j<c;++j) printf "; " a[i,j];
            print ""
          }
     }' <file>
```

Comment: Definitely interesting but the numbers of sections is likely to vary =/
Editing my question.

Comment: @EdouardIFP, could you please check my solution once and let me know?

Comment: @EdouardIFP I have updated my answer to allow a fully generic version where the number of rows and columns can vary.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I tried your generic version, it works fine as well.
I got a 62 seconds return time as well.

Answer (score 3):

Could you please try following once, considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples.

```
awk -v RS=""  '
{
  gsub(/\n|, /,",")
}
1' Input_file |
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/\([^\)]*/)){
     value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
     num=split(value,array,",")
     for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
       val[i]=val[i]?val[i] OFS array[i]:array[i]
     }
  }
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){
     print val[j]
  }
  delete val
  delete array
  value=""
}'   OFS="; "
```

***OR(above script is considering that numbers inside `(...)` will be constant, now adding script which will working even field numbers of not equal inside `(....)`.***

```
awk -v RS=""  '
{
  gsub(/\n/,",")
  gsub(/, /,",")
}
1'  Input_file |
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/\([^\)]*/)){
     value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
     num=split(value,array,",")
     for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
       val[i]=val[i]?val[i] OFS array[i]:array[i]
     max=num>max?num:max
     }
  }
  for(j=1;j<=max;j++){
     print val[j]
  }
  delete val
  delete array
}' OFS="; "
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1; 11; 111
2; 22; 222
3; 33; 333
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above code here.

```
awk -v RS=""  '                                      ##Setting RS(record separator) as NULL here.
{                                                    ##Starting BLOCK here.
  gsub(/\n/,",")                                  ##using gsub to substitute new line OR comma with space with comma here.
  gsub(/, /,",")
}
1' Input_file  |                                        ##Mentioning 1 will be printing edited/non-edited line of Input_file. Using | means sending this output as Input to next awk program.
awk '                                                ##Starting another awk program here.
{
  while(match($0,/\([^\)]*/)){                       ##Using while loop which will run till a match is FOUND for (...) in lines.
     value=substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)             ##storing substring from RSTART+1 to till RLENGTH-1 value to variable value here.
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                    ##Re-creating current line with substring valeu from RSTART+RLENGTH till last of line.
     num=split(value,array,",")                      ##Splitting value variable into array named array whose delimiter is comma here.
     for(i=1;i<=num;i++){                            ##Using for loop which runs from i=1 to till value of num(length of array).
       val[i]=val[i]?val[i] OFS array[i]:array[i]    ##Creating array val whose index is value of variable i and concatinating its own values.
     }
  }
  for(j=1;j<=num;j++){                               ##Starting a for loop from j=1 to till value of num here.
     print val[j]                                    ##Printing value of val whose index is j here.
  }
  delete val                                         ##Deleting val here.
  delete array                                       ##Deleting array here.
  value=""                                           ##Nullifying variable value here.
}'  OFS="; "                                         ##Making OFS value as ; with space here.
```

***NOTE:*** This should work for more than 3 values inside `(...)` brackets also.

Comment: Awesome, it works ! 

The script time just went from 80 to 62seconds, I expected larger gains, but the biggest benefit is that I just need to ensure awk's version stays the same instead of worrying about sed+awk.

Comment: @EdouardIFP I'm very convinced this can be faster. Even within a few seconds. How large is your file?

Comment: input file has 18.2 million lines of 10 digits decimal numbers for a total weight of 172Mb

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'BEGIN { RS = "\\s*[()]\\s*"; FS = "\\s*" }
NF > 0 {
  maxCol++
  if (NF > maxRow)
    maxRow = NF
  for (row = 1; row <= NF; row++)
    a[row,maxCol] = $row
}
END {
  for (row = 1; row <= maxRow; row++) {
    for (col = 1; col <= maxCol; col++)
      printf "%s", a[row,col] ";"
    print ""
  }
}' yourFile
```

output

```
1;11;111;
2;22;222;
3;33;333;
...;...;...;
```

Change `FS= "\\s*"` to `FS = "\n*"` when you also want to allow spaces inside your fields.

This script supports columns of different lengths.

When benchmarking also consider replacing `[i,j]` with `[i][j]` for GNU `awk`. I'm unsure which one is faster and did not benchmark the script myself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Perl one-liner solution

```
$ cat edouard2.txt
(1
2
3
a
)
(11
22
33
b
)
(111
222
333
c
)

$ perl -lne ' $x=0 if s/[)(]// ; if(/(\S+)/) { @t=@{$val[$x]};push(@t,$1);$val[$x++]=[@t] } END { print join(";",@{$val[$_]}) for(0..$#val) }' edouard2.txt
1;11;111
2;22;222
3;33;333
a;b;c
```

Comment: A very nice way to accumulate data, which I'd expect to be very efficient too.

Comment: agree completely!

Comment: @zdim.. need your help on qstn - 54026451 i'm not getting exact length of the columns as mentioned in the question ````perl -F, -lane ' print $#F  '````

Comment: If you mean that there isn't the same number of columns in their data, I get the same: 24, 25, 23.  (I confirmed by manually splitting it with a formatted print of all elems.)

Comment: @zdim..yes I too get the same, but the input has more number of columns.. The awk answers are correct.. but why less numbers in perl?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I didn't notice -- it seems that the `-F` drops the trailing (would-be empty) elements (after splitting). You can see that by echo-ing a line into a perl one-liner where you split it manually; it counts as 33; when I delete all those trailing commas in the echo-ed line -- voila, it's 25.  So apparently `-F` just drops them.

Comment: Is this expected in Perl.. so one-liner is not possible?

Comment: Ok..np take your own time

Comment: So, [split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) (mostly) drops empty fields,  and so does `-F`.  But this _doesn't_ happen when the string has a newline (as the last elem isn't empty then). So drop `-l` and it'll keep all fields, trailing empty ones included.  Manual `chomp` is OK, since by then all fields are in the array.  So: `echo "a,b,,," | perl -F, -anE'chomp @F; say $#F;`.  If you add `-l` then `$_` is `chomp`-ed before the `-F` does its thing and when it comes to splitting the trailing empty would-be fields are dropped. (And of course `chomp`-ing isn't always necessary.)

Comment: Another way to suppress removal of empty fields is to supply the optional argument (how many terms to return), explicitly telling it to give back everything: `split /,/, $_, -1`. This isn't possible to do for the automatic `-F` (as far as I can tell). But then any _line_ of a one-liner input, piped or from a file, will have a newline so not using `-l` will make `-F` keep all terms.

Comment: @zdim.. thank you for your analysis..it looks like a caveat and good to know.. I'll try them

Comment: Definitely a thing to know about `split`; I consider that to (most often) be a feature, that it drops would-be empty elements. So when you split by space you don't get that silly last element if there were trailing spaces in the string.  But then in this case it is indeed tricky.  The `split` has a few "specifics," details which one must know.  The function is supremely useful of course.  Note that `-F` may behave subtly differently so if you use one-liners check how `split`'s features work for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert each section to a row and then transpose after, e.g. assuming you are using GNU awk:

```
<infile awk '{ gsub("[( )]", ""); $1=$1 } 1' RS='\\)\n\\(' OFS=';' |
datamash -t';' transpose
```

Output:

```
1;11;111
2;22;222
3;33;333
...;...;...
```

Comment: The first arg to gsub() is a regexp, mot a string, so use regexp `/.../` not string `"..."` delimiters unless you have a specific reason to need awk to convert a string to a regexp before using it. Also, don't rely on `$1=$1` invoking a print as it won't always do so (consider the result if an input line was `0`), again only use actions in a condition context when you have a specific purpose in mind - use `{$1=$1}1` orr similar instead of just `$1=$1`.

Comment: @EdMorton: I used a string for aesthetic reasons. Does the OP want empty records printed? We don't know, so I chose the shorter version with a possibly desired side-effect

Comment: @EdMorton: `$1=$1` is wrong as it will remove any record that starts with a zero.  Updated the answer, thanks.

Comment: When comparing apples to apples it's fine to base a decision on aesthetics but when comparing "use the regexp" (`/.../`) with "convert the string to a regexp and  then use the regexp" (`"..."`) there are performance and functionality considerations that IMHO outweigh whether `/` or `"` looks prettier as the delimiter.