# Explode a number in bash

Tags: bash

How would I explode out a number in bash

With this value 
'12684041234'

Required result
'12684041234','1268404123','126840412','12684041','1268404','126840','12684','1268','126','12','1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that there's any built-in way to do what you want, but you can always use a loop:

```
n=12684041234
for (( i = ${#n}; i > 0; i-- )) do echo ${n:0:i}; done
```

This just loops from the length of the variable `$n` down to 1 and prints substrings of `$n`.

Answer (score 2):

The `%` can be used to remove prefix of a variable's value.

Give a try to this:

```
number=12684041234
while [[ "${#number}" -gt 0 ]] ; do
    printf ",'%s'" "${number}"
    number="${number%?}"
done | cut -b 2-
```

Output

```
'12684041234','1268404123','126840412','12684041','1268404','126840','12684','1268','126','12','1'
```

Comment: You can also use `while [[ -n $number ]]` to loop while the variable is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

if n is less than or equals `echo $((2**63-1))`

```
for((n=12684041234;n>0;n/=10));do echo $n;done
```

Comment: I like that loop. To match the output exactly, you could: `echo "'$n'"; done | paste -sd,`

Comment: @Nahuel... could you pls give a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53706983/splitting-a-large-complex-one-column-file-into-several-columns-with-awk/53918225#53918225 using perl..

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl and regex

```
$ echo '12684041234' | perl -ne  ' $x=$_;$i=length($x); while($i>0) { $x=~m/(.{$i})/m; print "$1\n" ; $i-- } '

12684041234
1268404123
126840412
12684041
1268404
126840
12684
1268
126
12
1
```

Thanks to Nahuel for the below solution

```
perl -nE '/^.+(?{say$&})(?!)/' <<<12684041234
```

Comment: or `perl -nE '/^.+(?{say$&})(?!)/' <<<12684041234`

Comment: @Nahuel.. yes it works..could you pls explain further.. I'll add to the answer

Comment: just golfed a bit for fun. explanation `/`..`/` is a regex, `.+` matches at least one character as many as possible, `(?{`code`})` allows to execute code after a partial match, to get submatches, `(?!)` makes the match fail and leads to backtracking, the `^` at beginning to anchor at the beginning, `-E` to use `say` to shorten.

Comment: about submatches removing anchor will give all substrings, note `export` is useless here, also `echo` + `|` makes a subshell which can be avoided using here-string

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ echo 12684041234 | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=""}{for(i=NF;i>=1;i--){print;NF--}}'
12684041234
1268404123
126840412
...
```

Answer (score 1):

with dc :

```
echo '12684041234' | dc -f - -e '[p10/d0<Z]sZlZx'
```

explanation :

```
# -f - is the file to read for the input (/dev/stdin)
# -e '...' is the code to execute

echo '12684041234' | dc -f - -e '
[
p       # print the stack
10
/       # divide the stack by 10
d       # duplicate the result
0
<Z      # while the stack is greater than 0 execute macro Z
] sZ    # define macro Z inside [ ]
lZ      # load macro Z
x       # execute it
'
```

Comment: it works... what is that you put in single quotes.. seems strange.. could you pls add explanation

Answer (score 1):

`sed` solution for fun:

```
$ sed -n ':a;p;s/.$//;/./ba' <<< 12684041234
12684041234
1268404123
126840412
12684041
1268404
126840
12684
1268
126
12
1
```

Answer (score -1):

I ain't thinkin' good practices, but to solver this problem. Here's how in Python the solution would be:

```
from functools import reduce

def f_split_word(s_word):
    return s_word

def f_list_explode_word(s_word):
    ret = []
    s_word_split = list(map(f_split_word, s_word))
    for x in range(0, len(s_word_split)):
        ret.append(reduce(lambda x,y: str(x) + str(y), s_word_split if x == 0 else s_word_split[:-x]))   
    return ret

s_word = str('12684041234')
print(f_list_explode_word(s_word))
```

[image]